# Where to check the underlying database details in Tridion 2013 SP1 CMS server

Tags: 2013-sp1, database, cm-db

For existing Tridion (2013 SP1) CMS installation is there any configuration file under the installation directory that stores the underlying database details for CMS like we have `cd_storage_conf.xml` in Deployer that stores the database details for published content?

Somehow the Tridion MMC Console is not working that is one option to figure out the DB configured for CMS server.

Answer (score 4):

`Tridion.ContentManager.Config` contains this information.

The database info is encrypted, follow the steps outlined [here](http://kahwah.me/2014/6/decrypting-encrypting-tridion-contentmanager-config) to read it.

From the linked article:

> To decrypt the configuration file, start with making a temporary directory somewhere to put the Tridion.ContentManager.config file. For this example we'll use `c:\temp`. From a new command prompt:

`mkdir c:\temp`

Copy the Tridion.ContentManager.config file to this directory and rename this file to web.config. Remember that the tool (aspnet_regiis.exe) was designed for web applications, so this is the reason why this step is necessary.

`copy c:\tridion_install_dir\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config c:\temp\web.config`

> Now it's time to decrypt the parts that are encrypted in this config file.

`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "database" c:\temp`

Comment: Thanks Nuno for sharing same; I got error while decryption and it seems if  we use <database configProtectionProvider="TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"> in config file it will fail. Error Message - "Failed to decrypt using provider 'TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened."

Comment: Your user doesn't have permissions to read the content. Use the account used to install Tridion, or the mtsuser account

Comment: To use the {domain}/MTSUser i need to reset the password for this domain user; is it ok to do this ? the fear is if tridion store MTSUser credentials encrypted in some conf files then reset password may break the things.

Comment: Yeah, stuff _will_ break if you change that password. Top of my head, any COM+ related code (if you have any) and Search will stop working.

Comment: Thanks Nuno for the confirmation; it helps to avoid creating new issues. I have raised separate thread to discuss more on this MTSUser issue https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17161/what-is-the-impact-if-we-reset-the-password-for-mts-user-tridion-2013-sp1

Comment: Just a heads-up for anyone trying to do this... I had to right click and select "Run as Administrator" on the Windows Command Prompt to get the unencryption command to work. Neither running as the MTS User nor the install user worked (access denied).

Answer (score 2):

The Tridion console is locked to specific users. The user who installed Tridion will have to give permissions to all other users, which can be an issue if the installer is not on the project.

A way around this is the following.

Download `psexec.exe` from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Open a command prompt in Admin view and navigate to the folder the psexec.exe is in

run the command `psexec -h cmd` (This will elevate the users token)

navigate to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` (Or whatever the .NET framework is)

Run the command `aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "<domain>\<account>"` (Where domain and user is updated to udm000\user.name